# Schedule Windows Server 2008 R2 to boot and shutdown

Tags: windows-server-2008, boot, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I just set up Win Server 2008 R2 + SQL Server 2008 R2, and i'd like to schedule two tasks.
One for shutting it down, or putting it to hibernate at a certain time, and one to wake him up.
Both tasks should run every day.
For booting up the system i tried to set up a scheduled task in the BIOS using the internal clock of the machine, but had no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to put the stress on the disks by having the machine shut down each night. I use the same procedure as sysadmin1138, except its a restart bi-weekly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you'll probably need a twofer.

1. A schedule task *in the OS* firing off `shutdown /h /t 2` at your scheduled time.
2. One of the following:

   1. A BIOS timer to *turn on* your server.
   2. Leverage Wake-on-LAN and issue a Wakeup packet at the exact time you want that server powered back on.

Comment: Also, the box may have remote-admin card (DRAC, iLO) with an SSH interface that could be fed a script for the power-on.

Comment: Thanks! Have to play a little bit more with the BIOS part, but that should be working...

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown is pretty easy.  Create a scheduled task with the following command line:

```
shutdown /s /t 60 /c "Scheduled shutdown"
```

That will shut down the computer after popping up a 60-second warning.  It will force any stuck programs to close, and will leave a comment in the system event log.

I can't think of any feature of Windows that would let you schedule a startup - that's normally the domain of the BIOS.  In a quick test I performed on a Dell workstation, I had to enable "Auto Power On", then set the power-on time.  I suspect that some other BIOS's may be less intuitive.

For a more exotic and Rube Goldberg-esque solution, you could enable wake-on-LAN and send a wake-up packet from a neighboring computer.  However, I've never been able to make that work myself.

Finally, I have to wonder whether you should even be turning off your server in the first place.  The vast majority of servers stay on all the time.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable way to save power, if a server's only used during the day and doesn't have great power management.